# How to upload file, using curl, to python-eve field that is inside a dict type

Tags: python, curl, eve

I try to figure out if I can upload media files, using curl (or anything else really), to python-eve field that *is inside a dict type*.

The documentation, http://docs.python-eve.org/en/latest/features.html, only have the simple example of

```py
accounts = {
    ...,
    'pic': {'type': 'media'},
    ...
}
```

```
curl -F "pic=@profile.jpg"
```

But what about this one?

```py
accounts = {
    ...,
    'extras': {
        'type': 'dict',
        'schema': {
            'pic': {'type': 'media'},
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried with
    curl -F "extras.pic=@profile.jpg", 
    curl -F "extras:pic=@profile.jpg"
etc

I've also experimented with *sub resources* without luck.

I am about to accept that I'm not allowed to structure my schema as I wish, but if there is a way, I'd be very happy to know.

Comment: Have you seen the media file storage section in python-eve documentation yet ? https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#file-storage

Comment: Have you been able to this? I'm trying it with no luck...

Comment: @EliasGarcia no, no luck here either.

Comment: How about uploading multiple media files at once? Already activated AUTO_COLLAPSE_MULTI_KEYS = True, 
AUTO_CREATE_LISTS = True, MULTIPART_FORM_FIELDS_AS_JSON = True

Comment: The link [https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/eve/flaskapp.py#L615] is a 404 unfortunately. It is supposed to describe this very problem according to [https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/932]. Thanks for your help anyway